# WPF DVC:Lineseries Style and axes settings using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-visualization, wpftoolkit

I am trying to Plot some simple Line Charts ...  I Thought. I've done this so far:

XAML

```
<DVC:Chart x:Name="DVA_Cycle_Chart" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
<DVC:Chart.Axes>
   <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Title="Zeit"/>
      <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Location="Left" Title="Volumenstrom Q "/>
      <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Location="Right" Title="Druck p"/>
   </DVC:Chart.Axes>
</DVC:Chart>
```

This generates a Chart where the x-axis is labeled with "Zeit", the left y-axis with "Volumenstrom Q " and the right y-axis with "Druck p". Fine.
Now I added two Lineseries:

C#

```
KeyValuePair<double, double>[] single_pressure_KeyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<double, double>[2];
KeyValuePair<double, double>[] single_flow_rate_KeyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<double, double>[2];
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      {
       single_pressure_KeyValuePair[i] = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(i, 3);
       single_flow_rate_KeyValuePair[i] = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(i, 4);
      }

     LineSeries single_pressure_LS = new LineSeries();
     single_pressure_LS.Title = "Pressure";
     single_pressure_LS.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Key");
     single_pressure_LS.DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value");
     single_pressure_LS.ItemsSource = single_pressure_KeyValuePair;
     DVA_Cycle_Chart.Series.Add(single_pressure_LS);

     LineSeries single_flow_rate_LS = new LineSeries();
     single_flow_rate_LS.Title = "Flow Rate";
     single_flow_rate_LS.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Key");
     single_flow_rate_LS.DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value");
     single_flow_rate_LS.ItemsSource = single_flow_rate_KeyValuePair;
     DVA_Cycle_Chart.Series.Add(single_flow_rate_LS);
```

This leads to two simple horizontal Lines! Fine. Unfortunately, Both Lines are related to the left Y-Axis, but I want to relade the first series to the left and the second series to the right y-Axis. Where can I set up this. I perfer to do this in C# instead of XAML.
Small extra question: how can I set the range of an axis? Lets say I want to plot x values between x=0.5 and x=33.1.

Google showed me a lot of related posts but non answered this question. Does anyone know where to find a complete documentation of DVC:Chart from WPF Toolbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the corresponding `LinearAxis` code from your XAML and define it in code-behind like this:

```
    single_pressure_LS.DependentRangeAxis = new LinearAxis {
        Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y,
        Location = AxisLocation.Left,
        Title = "Volumenstrom Q",
        Minimum = 1,
        Maximum = 4 };
    single_flow_rate_LS.DependentRangeAxis = new LinearAxis {
        Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y,
        Location = AxisLocation.Right,
        Title = "Druck p",
        Minimum = 3,
        Maximum = 5 };
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot this works fine! Maybe you even know how to set the color of the datapoints and the backgroundcolor? Again I found examples in XAML only ...

Comment: Ok to influence the color of the line I figured out to use  Style DataPointStyle_Red = new Style(typeof(DataPoint));   with the Setter  DataPointStyle_Red.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataPoint.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));  and finally  single_pressure_LS.DataPointStyle = DataPointStyle_Red;